# Rails Authorize Editor and Correct User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to have correct users, admins, and editors be able to edit, update, and delete a blog.

I have this in my Blogs controller:

```
before_action :require_user, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy, :can_edit_blog?]
```

and this in under private:

```
    def can_edit_blog?
      true if ((current_user.admin? || current_user.editor?) || correct_user)
    end

    def correct_user
      @blog = current_user.blogs.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @blog.nil?
    end
```

Right now it only allows the correct user, but not the admin or editors. I've tried using another before_action :admin_user, but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
    before_action :require_creator, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

    ...

    def can_edit_blog?
        current_user.admin? || current_user.editor?
    end

    def require_creator
        @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
        redirect_to root_url unless (current_user == @blog.user || can_edit_blog?)
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an app that has some similar logic. Here is what my controller code would look like. Some of the private methods can be abstracted to the ApplicationController.

```
before_action :require_user, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :require_creator, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

private

  def require_user
    access_denied unless logged_in?
  end

  def logged_in?
    !!current_user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def access_denied
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def require_creator
    access_denied unless logged_in? and (current_user == @blog.user || current_user.admin?)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to call `can_edit_blog` in the `:only` option of the `before_action` calling `correct_user`.  You want to call `can_edit_blog?` in `correct_user`:

```
before_action :correct_user?, only: [:edit, :update, :delete]

...

private

  def can_edit_blog?
    current_user.admin? || current_user.editor?
  end

  def correct_user
    @blog = current_user.blogs.find_by(id: params[:id])
    if @blog.nil? or not can_edit_blog?
      redirect_to root_url 
    end
  end
```

## OP's solution is correct, mine is not, refer to their updated question

Comment: I just tried that and my admin wasn't granted permission... I did change your suggestion of :correct_user? to :correct_user because I didn't have a method correct_user?

Comment: Are you sure that your `admin?` method works then?  Or is your user really defined as `admin?`?  If you are using `byebug` in your Gemfile, could you please put the following line: `debugger` into the beginning of `can_edit_blog?` and then head to your console, enter `current_user.admin?` into the byebug console input, hit enter, and see if it returns true or false?

Comment: it returns true... by logic it should work. I just tinkered with your suggestion and it works now. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I wonder if mine wasn't working because of the `@blog.nil?` check.  Is `@blog` supposed to be `nil` when you are an admin?

Comment: Good point.. I haven't checked. I'll keep that in mind as I continue. Thanks again!

Comment: Good luck!  And keep having fun!